# Exit 2 For loop when condition is met in a 3 For loop nested system in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, nested-loops, exit

I am trying to write a code which has multiple For and If loops. I will try to explain the problem first where the dataset I have is like the following in column 'AH':
0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,..... where the number of 0s, 1s and 2s in a stretch is unknown. What I am trying to find the number of cycles, where a cycle is defined when there has to be atleast 3 0s in a stretch and then has to be atleast 4 2s consecutively. So, to do that, I wrote the code in the following format

```
    Dim M As Single: Dim Count As Integer: Dim A As Integer: Dim B As Integer
    M = 2: Count = 0: A =3: B=4
    Dim temp As Integer: Dim temp1 As Integer: temp = 0
    
    For L = M To 50 
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AJ" & M) = M
      temp = 0
      For L1 = L To L + A
        temp = temp + Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH" & L1)
      Next L1
      If temp = 0 Then
       N = L + A
       For N1 = N To 60 
         If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH" & N1) = 2 Then
            temp1 = 0
            For I1 = N1 To N1 + B
                temp1 = temp1 + Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH" & I1)
            Next I1
            If temp1 = 2 * B Then
                flg = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next N1
        Count = Count + 1: M = I1
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AJ2") = Count
    If flg = True Then Exit For
End If
M = M + 1
Next L
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is find the first 0 and count the sum of 3 consecutive values. If it is 0, then I am searching for 2. When the first 2 is found, it will add up the next 4 terms and if the sum is equal to 2*4, then I will update the count and the code should start look for 0. However, using the 'Exit For' puts me out of all the loops. And if I don't put Exit, then it keep counting the 2s for more times. I am new to VBA and struck with this problem for a long time. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bit of a dirty hack, but you could put a line label (`LabelName:`) just before the `Next` statement for the *outer* loop you want to resume to, and then have `GoTo LabelName` in the *inner* loop you want to get out of. A cleaner fix would be to re-evaluate whether and how the loops need to be nested. An out-of-the-box alternative approach could be to join the cell values into a string, and then to use a regular expression that matches at least 3 consecutive zeroes followed by at least 4 consecutive twos - then you could simply iterate the regex matches captured.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh8kO.png) might be a start (that's regex101.com)

Comment: Thank you very much @MathieuGuindon. I am trying as you mentioned and will get back to you.